# Using ngbTooltip Inside ngSwitch Throws Error When Destroyed

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ng-switch

I'm using Angular 2 and ng-bootstrap.  I've got an `[ngSwitch]` with different tooltips defined in the content based on the case.

When the `[ngSwitch]` variable changes, the tooltip throws an exception: this._unregisterListenersFn is not a function at NgbTooltip.ngOnDestroy.

I'm not sure if this could be a glitch with the ng-bootstrap library or if I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the offending code:

```
<div [ngSwitch]='jobStatusItem.type'>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor='let item of filteredItems()'>
            <span *ngSwitchCase='"job"'>
                <template #tooltipContent>Details</template>
                <span (click)='loadItem(item)' [ngbTooltip]='tooltipContent'>
                    <img src='...' />
                </span>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the error message:
[image]

I'm able to change the `jobStatusItem.type` once without problems, but the second time it throws the error.